# PDF encoding issue

Tags: java, pdf, encoding

I am having difficulty receiving a PDF file via a rest service. The rest service returns a long string with the data that is suppose to make up the PDF. My overall goal is to save the response as a PDF file for later use.

I call this service url: http://4.hidemyass.com/ip-2/encrypted/dnXuHKAZVZaONS2GNfC9RFn8k8puE2YJx6MjcPDMaKdpMRTBkvNF4CrTg4m7GeKjcLfO1bgYWIwR9bz1ZJP-LTK6Gm8tG_-d4V-oSUMfT-tIJMuZizsz9AeZp5tcZWVcz62A6j7YRWqJRAS_s_cMFLlo&f=norefer

and according the docs, it should be the string contents that make up a valid PDF.

What am I missing? What do I need to do in order to make is viewable as a PDF.

Thanks!

Chuc

Comment: To view the URL above, paste it into your address bar. HideMyAss blocks hot linking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry the above link failed.

In the end we found that sending the PDF as binary data wrapped in JSON did not work very well. The creators of the service found that their framework was manipulating the binary data ever so slightly and converting some characters. They ended up switching to Base 64 encoding which worked great.